# I can't find my branch in github, that i created on git

Tags: git, github

I have created a branch called 'Samwel_Mchomvu' in git, I checkedout and create another branch called Samwel_Operation under which i added my task.
After pushing to github i found a branch Samwel_Operation and i did not find Samwel_Mchomvu as my master branch of which Samwel_Operation expected to be under it. Here is a screen shot in git and github.

Anyone who can help me

[image: git screen shot]

here is a github screenshot
[image: here is a github screenshot]

Comment: Did you ever do a `git push origin Samwel_Mchomvu`? Until you push a branch to github it's not going to show up.

Comment: i did not push Samwel_Mchomvu thanks let me do it

Comment: @Mark it worked out, where can i put a tick as the solution worked out

Comment: I put my comment as an answer. You should be able to put the ticket. I was initially just clarifying that you had tried. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `git push origin Samwel_Mchomvu`. Until you push a branch to github it's not going to show up.